# Система выдачи ролей

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

имеется команда для запроса роли. Не понимаю, как задать для реакций некоторые функции.

```
@client.command()
async def role( ctx):

    role = ctx.guild.get_role(
        703596629860548643
    )  

    zapros_chanell = client.get_channel( 729733881129074768 ) 
    zapros2_chanell = client.get_channel( 703596629923725339 ) 
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Запрос роли")
    embed.add_field(name='Запросивший роль', value=ctx.message.author.mention)
    embed.add_field(name='Роль для выдачи', value=f'{role.mention}' )

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)

    message = await zapros_chanell.send(embed=embed)
    await zapros2_chanell.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, `запрос на выдачу роли был успешно отправлен, ожидайте его рассмотрения модерацией Discord`', color=discord.Color.purple()))
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❎')
```

Суть в том, что бы если при нажатии на ✅ роль выдавалась и в zapros2_chanell человеку писался текст.

При нажатии на ❎ человеку роль не выдавалась следовательно, но и в zapros2_chanell писался определенный текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ждать события `"on_reaction_add"`: `bot.wait_for("reaction_add")`
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

```py
from asyncio import TimeoutError as AsyncTimeoutError

@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    control_emojis = ["✅", "❎"]
    for e in control_emojis:
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(e)
    try:
        r, u = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 30, check = lambda r, u: (str(r) in control_emojis) and u == ctx.author)
    except AsyncTimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Ты слишком долго плавал…")
        return
    if str(r) == "✅":
        await ctx.send("Подтверждено")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Отклонено")
```